# How to start a service even if phone is locked in android

Tags: android, service

I am creating a chat head service which starts on an incoming call . I want to open the chat head on an incoming call . I am able to do this only if my screen is opened . How can I achieve this even if my app is locked? Please help me.

My chat head service class :

```
package com.tarun.notifyme2;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

        private WindowManager windowManager;
        private ImageView chatHead;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            int res = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            return res;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            chatHead = new ImageView(this);
            chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell2);
            chatHead.setClickable(true);

            params= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            params.x = 0;
            params.y = 200;

            chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatHeadService.this,"You clicked  the imageview",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("tag","You clicked the imageview");
                    startActivity(new Intent(ChatHeadService.this, SendNoti.class)
                                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                    stopSelf();
                }
            });

            //this code is for dragging the chat head
            chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;
                int flag=0;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        if(flag==3){
                            flag=1;
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            flag=1;
                            return false;
                        }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if(flag==3){
                            flag=2;
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            flag=2;
                            return false;
                        }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        flag=3;
                        params.x = initialX
                                + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY
                                + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                        return true;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You ckiced the imageview",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("tag","You clicked the imageview");
                    /*
                    Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),SendNoti.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    stopSelf();*/
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
            /*
            Snackbar.make(chatHead, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
            windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (chatHead != null)
                windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My class which detects both incoming and outgoing class

```
    package com.tarun.notifyme2;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    /**
     * Created by Tarun Talreja on 13-08-2016.
     */
    public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        static String outgoingNo;
        static String incomingNo;
        private Context mContext;
        private Intent mIntent;
        public OutgoingCallReceiver() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            String state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mContext = context;
            mIntent = intent;
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
            tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
            /*
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)) {

                // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call

                // get the phone number
                String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                incomingNo = incomingNumber;
                context.startService(new Intent(context, ChatHeadService.class));

            }else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                    || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                // This code will execute when the call is disconnected

                Toast.makeText(context, "Detected call hangup event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                context.stopService(new Intent(context, ChatHeadService.class));
            }
            */
        }
        private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                String callState = "UNKNOWN";
                switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        callState = "IDLE";
                        mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, ChatHeadService.class));
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        // -- check international call or not.
                        if (incomingNumber.startsWith("00")) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext,"International Call- " + incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            callState = "International - Ringing (" + incomingNumber+ ")";
                            incomingNo = incomingNumber;
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Local Call - " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            callState = "Local - Ringing (" + incomingNumber + ")";
                            incomingNo = incomingNumber;
                        }
                        mContext.startService(new Intent(mContext, ChatHeadService.class));
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        String dialingNumber = mIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                        /*
                        if (dialingNumber.startsWith("00")) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext,"International - " + dialingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            callState = "International - Dialing (" + dialingNumber+ ")";
                            outgoingNo=dialingNumber;
                        } else {
                            */
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Local Call - " + dialingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            callState = "Local - Dialing (" + dialingNumber + ")";
                            outgoingNo=dialingNumber;
                        //}
                        break;
                }
                Log.i(">>>Broadcast", "onCallStateChanged " + callState);
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: In case of incoming call  when the screen is locked, is the broadcast reciever working?

Comment: No the broadcast receiver is not working if incoming call comes

Comment: Sorry my mistake the broadcast receiver works very well even if the phone is locked +ArJ